# How to lock up folders on mac desktop?

Tags: macos

I would like to keep certain folders on my desktop for easily saving screenshots I want. But I delete all the things fairly often, and I delete these as well.

Is there a way to "lock" these folders so they cannot be deleted?

Comment: When you go to delete everything, why is it you must delete these folders too? If you want to keep them, keep them.

Comment: i press cmd-a , cmd - del - it is just a very handy thing i do

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete the folder contents but not the folder, itself, or clean off the desktop but leave those selected folders untouched?

Comment: Simply changing 'program' to 'way' puts this right back on-topic again. It's a perfectly answerable question, & already has a decent answer.

Comment: If I correctly understand, you may use symbolic link to another part in the path: eg. directory `All/Save01` on your Desktop as a link to `/home/ming/SafePath/Save01`.  So if you delete accidentally the current directory `All` under the Desktop, it will remain the directory under SafePath... (warning the command you use it can affect linked path too..)

Answer (score 2):

A few ways of doing this.

1 - Store the actual folders/files in a different location and make an 'alias' to them on your desktop (hold option-command while dragging)

2 - Right click folder - Get Info - enable Locked

3 - chown the files as root which will then require authentication to delete

Comment: But won't the OP just end up deleting the aliases when he deletes everything from the desktop?

Comment: Yes but he wouldn't be deleting the source files at least.  You could also resort to tricks such as chowning them as root so it presents you with a password request before it will delete.

Comment: I vote you include that in your answer. It's obvious the OP wants to be able to delete everything on the desktop but somehow be prevented from deleting these certain folders.

Comment: Perhaps but I think it's bad practice to have someone get 'used to' deleting everything from a folder without considering what they're deleting.

Comment: Agreed. I made the same point to the OP. You could always state in your answer *you don't want to do this...and here's why.* I'd post an answer but I don't know Macs very well.

Comment: this is brilliant! thanks everyone so much. i store my important files on the cloud, so i am typically good there. :)